# Remove shadow - paper dialog (Polymer)

Tags: polymer

I know this is somewhat like a hack, and dialogs are meant to have shadows. However I'm using `paper-dialog` in the form of a bottom sheet in my application. I want to remove the `elevation/shadow` of the dialog. How can I achieve this?

Comment: As far as I can see [here](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dialog-behavior/blob/master/paper-dialog-shared-styles.html), there is no mixin available to style the shadow. You can, however, edit the `shadow.html` file and remove the `box-shadow` property there, but this solution feels a bit wrong, since you are editing the element's source code.

Comment: @alesc I agree with what you said. Editing components is not such a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I just added the following style and the shadow is gone

```
<style>
    paper-dialog { box-shadow: none; }
</style>
```